# Can't pass argument to pyqtslot using lambda

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to use lambda expression to pass an instance as an argument to a slot, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'
```

I've tried both lambda and partial to pass the instance argument but neither method worked.

The reason why I want to do this is that I want to reuse the same method in a couple of different classes.

```py
class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.ui.xOffsetSpinBox.editingFinished.connect(lambda: AppWindow.on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished(self))
    ...

  @staticmethod
  def on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished(instance):
    ...
```

I want to use this static method as a slot for another signal in a different dialogue class.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR;** What is failing is the auto-connection provided by Qt Designer, and not your explicit connection.

---

I suppose that `ui` is an object of a class generated by Qt Designer, if you check the code generated by pyuic the following instruction should be:

```py
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(...)
```

The [`connectSlotsByName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) method makes an auto-connection if the slot has the following pattern:

```
def on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>):
    # ...
```

In your case `on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished` meets that requirement since it has an `xOffsetSpinBox` object that is a `QSpinBox` that has an `editingFinished` signal, that you can check if you comment on the connection you made and you will see that you still observe the same problem.

---

A possible solution is change the name of the static method so that it does not match the indicated pattern, for example:

```py
class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ui.xOffsetSpinBox.editingFinished.connect(lambda: AppWindow.on_another_name(self))
        # ...

    @staticmethod
    def on_another_name(instance):
        # ...
```

Another solution is to use the [@pyqtSlot()](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) decorator by passing a name parameter that does not match the indicated pattern.

```py
class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ui.xOffsetSpinBox.editingFinished.connect(lambda: AppWindow.on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished(self))
        # ...

    @staticmethod
    @pyqtSlot(name="static_connection")
    def on_xOffsetSpinBox_editingFinished(instance):
        # ...
```

Comment: It worked by changing the method name! So in a word it's the auto-connection that's failing not my explicit connect(), is that correct?

Comment: @Akahs Exactly, that's what I wanted to explain